# How made a library with Angular 2 on npm?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, node-modules

I made a simple library on Angular 2, but when I try to use it on a project I get error 404.

This is my code, I don't know if i am doing something wrong...

=> package.json

```
{
  "name": "module_testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "node module with Angular 2 test",
  "main": "module_testing.js",
  "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "prepublish": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
      "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
      "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
      "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
      "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
      "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",

      "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
      "systemjs": "0.19.40",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
      "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
      "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  },
  "keywords": [
      "test"
  ],
  "typings": "./module_testing.d.ts",
  "author": "Danny",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

=> tsconfig.json

```
{


 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
        "module_testing.ts"
    ]
}
```

=> src/test.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService{
  test() {
    alert('Working');
  }
}
```

=> module_testing.ts

```
export * from './src/test.service';
```

I'm testing the service on Angular 2 quickstart project

=> app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from 'module_testing/module_testing';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testService.test();
  }

}
```

I'm using node 6.9.1 and npm 4.0.2

This is the structure of the library.

[image]

And the error.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to import the service into 'app.module.ts' as well

Comment: I added the service into app.module.ts, but I get the same error.

Comment: Why are you importing `TestService` from `module_testing/module_testing`? Shouldn't it be imported from `/test.service` since thats is where it resides?

Comment: That's why the first 'module_testing' it's the name of the library and the second it's the name of the file that export the service. I edited the code in the question.